# Password field in django admin not displaying value

Tags: python, django

I have a Crew Model. The table has a password field. I dont want to display password in plain text. So I have added forms where I have used `widget=forms.PasswordInput()`. But this doesnt display the password after saving the data. How do I display password in hidden format?

```
class Crew(models.Model):
     crew_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     crew_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)
     crew_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
     crew_password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
```

Forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
      crew_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

      class Meta:
           model = Crew
           fields = ('crew_name', 'crew_password', 'crew_code', 'crew_id')
```

[image]

Comment: post your view too, how you are saving the data, and what do you mean by not showing the password? not displaying or is displayed in plain text?

Comment: Once the password is saved you can't view it. Just the hash.

Comment: Why do you want to store and display the password in plain text? This is a _huge_ security misstep, and you might have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I am using default django CMS. So I have not written the save method in views.py.

Comment: You **must not** do this. Use Django's built-in authentication system.

Comment: As @DanielRoseman mentioned, use django's default auth system to save password if you are not doing that. use `user.set_password()` to set your password. This will save your password as a hash. If you just want to fill the password field with some characters, just fill it using javascript. Never use your real password to fill in password field. That will become a severe security issue.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to safe passwords ( I totally agree this is not the way for django users, but I do have some other connections with passwords saved) you should have a look at django-extensions, using python-keyczar to encrypt passwords).

To answer your question, i aslo found out the password widget does not show whether a password is filled in or empty. (i would expect dots or asterics to show there is something in the field, but should not be shown of course).

this does that exactly:

```
class SomeConnectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(render_value = True),
        }
```

the trick is the render_value=True